# PHP appends file text to all javaScript files

Tags: javascript, php, file, pthreads

I don't know why a text from a file is appended to all the .js files in my project. I have a text file that I read from, which contains a single string, to my surprise, it appends the string to all .js files which disable them from loading. What am I to do right?

Basically, the text in the file is `ken4ward`. The text is just called in a PHP file.

```
session_start();
    require_once('send.txt');
    require_once('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/register/DBConnect.php');

    $myFile = "send.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $myFileContents = fread($fh, 21);
    fclose($fh);
    $mytrimmedvalue = trim($myFileContents);
```

The error I'm getting on the console

```
 [Show/hide message details.] ReferenceError: ken4ward is not defined[Learn More] yui_combo.php:1:1
[Show/hide message details.] ReferenceError: ken4wardM is not defined[Learn More] javascript-static.js:1:1
SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier[Learn More] require.min.js:1:12
[Show/hide message details.] TypeError: require is not a function[Learn More] search.php:1584:1
[Show/hide message details.] TypeError: Y is undefined[Learn More] search.php:1725:14
```

Comment: If `send.txt` only has the word `ken4ward` in it then your php code will try to see that as php code. But `ken4ward` is not php code. It's just a word. It tries a few things to resolve it but it obviously can't. It would be the same as simply writing that word in your code. What is the reason for including the word in your code? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are including the

```
require_once('send.txt');
```

on top of the page, PHP tries to treat the text in it as a variable. You can simply remove that line of text which is not needed. This piece of code will do the job for you.

```
$myFile = "send.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$myFileContents = fread($fh, 21);
fclose($fh);
$mytrimmedvalue = trim($myFileContents);
```